# How to use require.js to load Vue.js and my custom Vue library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, requirejs

I wrote a widget in `Vue.js` and compiled it as a library.

I want to attach my widget to 3rd party website which uses `require.js` to load scripts.

I'm using following code to load Vue and my widget:

```
<script>
    require([
        'vue',
        'myWidget'
    ], function (Vue, myWidget) {
        console.log('Loaded!');
    });
</script>
```

**but I get an error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>   myWidget.js:8

How I should load both `Vue.js` and my widget correctly?

Comment: Does `myWidget` load `vue` as well? It has been a while since I used `require.js`, but if I recall correctly, `require.js` load files asynchronously, so `myWidget` probably load before `vue` as finished loading.

Comment: No, `myWidget` is not loading `vue` itself. On another website I'm loading both `vue.js` and `myWidget.js` using 2 script tags, however here I need to load it through `require.js`.

Comment: If you can modify `myWidget`, add `vue` as a dependency. If you cannot change it, try to load `vue`, then load `myWidget` in the callback.

Comment: If you just try this without loading 'myWidget' and just attempt to load Vue - does that even work?

Comment: @MattOestreich Yes, it works fine and when I `console.log(Vue)` it gives me correct output.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I tried loading `myWidget` in callback but it gives me the same error. I can't build this widget bundled with `Vue`.

Comment: Maybe `Vue` is not available globally. Try, before loading your widget, `window.Vue = Vue;`. Not clean, but might works.

Comment: What does your widget look like? I am not too familiar with require.js but I know your components have to be written in a certain manner to use them as Vue plugins.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Well... I couldn't make new instance of Vue in console before, after I added `window.Vue = Vue;` I can, however this didn't solve problem.

Comment: @MattOestreich It's standard `Vue.js` app built as library (`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib [entry]`). I'm using this widget on 2 another websites by including `script` tag for `vue.js` and `myWidget.js`. Everything work well, but when I wanted to add my widget to Magento 2 website which uses `require.js` I got this issue.

Comment: [HERE](http://codematic.tech/spare-parts-finder) is the sample page with `vue.js` and `myWidget.js` loaded directly through `script` tag and everything works well. Also, my widget is built as UMD bundle `(A UMD bundle for consuming directly in browsers or with AMD loaders)`

Comment: @JoeyNie - good work! Sorry I wasn't more help...